# Can this angle be the same at any width?

Tags: css, geometry, clip-path

I'm trying to make a div with an angled bottom edge have the same angle no matter the viewport width.

Using `clip-path` produced the smoothest edge but I can't figure out if there's a `calc()` I can use to maintain the angle.

A skewed pseudo element works but has poor anti-aliasing so I want to avoid that.

So my question is: using `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(/* what goes here */, 0 100%)` what is in `calc()` such that the angle θ is 86% at all widths of side A?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to calculate. Could you draw a sketch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not going to be possible to calculate solely with CSS as you would require trigonometry methods (`sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`).

> **UPDATE:**
>
> [CSS to get support for trigonometry functions](https://www.zdnet.com/article/css-to-get-support-for-trigonometry-functions/)

If you need to make the calculation and apply it to a static, non-responsive polygon, Sass is your friend here. Otherwise, [JavaScript Math functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) is the only answer.

**EDIT: Calculation**

Assuming you have the following shape, where ABCD is your desired shape (E is included to help with the calculation):

```
A                                        B
o----------------------------------------o
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        o C
|                                        |
|                                        |
o----------------------------------------o
D                                          E
```

The trick here is to find the length of `CE` and subtract that from the total height.

If we start by looking at the right-angled triangle `CDE`. The angle `< DCE` is actually equal to the angle `< ADB` (the `86deg` you desire). We also know the length of `DE` - `100%`, but lest just take that as a unitless value for now. This gives us enough to calculate the length of `CE`.

```
DE = 100
< DCE = 86deg
```

Using the following trigonometry calculation:

```
tan(@) = <opposite-length> / <adjacent-length>
tan(@) = DE / CE
// Let's put in what we know
tan(86) = 100 / CE
CE = 100 / tan(86)
```

Using this, and assuming the height of `BE` is `100` (or `100%`) we can then find the length of `BC` with the following:

```
BC = BE - CE
// BE == AD (which you will be able to use programatically)
BC = AD - CE
BC = 100 - CE
BC = 100 - [100 / tan(86)] = 93.0073%
// so your calculation would be:
BC = AD - [AD / tan(86)] * 1%
```

Therefore, co-ordinate `C` should be `100%, 93.0073%`

***ref***

[image: Trigonometry helper]

Comment: Great answer, thanks Colm! As it's responsive it'll have to be the JS.

Comment: Great answer. Kudos.